# Comma Operator PHP

Tags: php, boolean, operators

Both these statements are true:

```
$_POST['foo'] = $_POST['bar'] = 'some string';

//1. with '&&' operator
if(isset($_POST['foo']) && isset($_POST['bar'])) { 
    echo true; 
}

//2. with a comma
if(isset($_POST['foo'], $_POST['bar'])) { 
    echo true; 
}
```

What is the difference (if any) between them?

Comment: Comma isn't strictly an operator, it's an argument separator. The [isset()](http://www.php.net/function.isset) function can accept one _or more_ arguments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There IS a difference, in practice. The meaning should be the same, however the "comma operator" version implements a "complete boolean evaluation" in this case. That is, if the first variable is not set, php won't look at the second since they're in a && relationship and the result can't be true anymore. (This is called a "short circuit" eval) In the second case, php must calculate both arguments before calling isset(...) so both values will be checked.

It's just the principle, yes, but sometimes it's very important, for example if the operands are function calls.

*(Just a short reply to the commenter saying "isset does not take function calls" - it's not about isset, it's about implementing expressions in general. Stop calculating things as soon as the result is obvious, and spare yourself as many partial results as you can. Function arguments will do the opposite: they all get calculated before they get passed to the subroutine.)*

Comment: But `isset(...)` does not accept function as operands so your principle is invalid.

Comment: @dkellner If you are correct using the && operator could be a lot less expensive if you were checking a large number of variables... like multiple arrays...

Comment: Indeed. Not just less expensive but it can be a completely different thing - considering what happens if the second argument is a function call that (for example) halts with an error. You'll only get this effect when the first argument is true - it's a nightmare when debugging. (OF COURSE IT'S NOT about isset now; as I said it's the principle of && vs arguments. Sure, isset with functions makes little sense but the question goes beyond that.)

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference according to the PHP documentation: [isset() function](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php). Indeed, `isset` can take an infinity of argument and returns true if every variable passed exists. It's similar to test if each isset() of each variable is true.

The theory should be check, but the function takes only variable in argument as said by the doc:

> isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the defined() function.

... So there's no problem about priority of the compute of arguments.

Finally, be aware that the comma here isn't an operator. The comma here is used to separated arguments of the `isset` function. The previous explanation doesn't work with `empty()` for example since [the `empty` function only takes 1 argument](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.empty.php).

**TL;DR**: `isset($a, $b) == isset($a) && isset($b)`, but `empty($a, $b)` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The `isset()` function can accept multiple arguments. If multiple arguments are supplied, then it only returns true if **all** of them are set.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference, except for the fact that you are calling isset() twice in 1., effectively evaluating both returning values with the && operator, in 2. you are just using isset() with two arguments instead of one, separated with a comma.

Comment: behind the scenes, doesn't php break the arguments up and test each one?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the inner workings of isset() since I have not seen its code, however I believe it does but that is a different matter than calling a function twice.